# Symfony / Orocrm : yml file is not set?

Tags: php, symfony, datagrid, orocrm

Website : Open source frameword based on Symfony 2.7
My entitie : Entity/Download.php (with properties "id", "creation_date" and "name")

I'm working on my own Bundle and I try to create a new datagrid based on my own entitie, [I follow this tutorial](https://oroinc.com/doc/orocommerce/1.5/dev-guide/entities/datagrids). Below is what I've done :

- Create /resources/config/datagrid.yml, with a very light datagrid.
- Edit DependencyInjection/MyBundleExtension.php to load datagrid.yml.
- Edit my twig view to render the datagrid :

> {% import 'PimDataGridBundle::macros.html.twig' as dataGrid %}
>
> {% block content %}
>   {{ dataGrid.renderGrid('custom_download', { localeCode: locale_code() }) }}
>
> {% endblock %}

But this error is generated :

> Twig_Error_Runtime: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering
>   of a template ("A configuration for "custom_download" datagrid was not
>   found.

-> If I try the same code with another gridname already existing that works then I believe the problem comes from my new datagrid but I don't understand what's wrong : does the kernel include my YML config file ? I don't think so.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create **datagrid.yml** in **/resources/config** folder.
But according OroPlatform conventions configuration file should be placed in **Resources/config/oro** folder of your bundle and named **datagrids.yml**.
Exactly in this path OroPlatform is looking for datagrid configuration.
https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/2.5/src/Oro/Bundle/DataGridBundle/Provider/ConfigurationProvider.php#L154-L160

Please move your configuration into correct directory and filename. And It will be work. And of course you should remove this file loading from DependencyInjection/MyBundleExtension.php OroPlatform do it automatically.

For more detailed understanding how you can use OroPlatform datagrid features please read bundle documentation
https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/2.5/src/Oro/Bundle/DataGridBundle/Resources/doc/backend/datagrid.md

Comment: That's it ! Thanks !

Comment: hi Vitaliy Berdylo, My Magento Version 1.9.2.3, i have installed Bitnami OroCRM in Windows. After successfully installed then i going to Sync. The Sync is not complete i am getting an error like, Jobs Failed  1) oro_integration:sync_integration:1  2)  orocrm_magento:sync_initial_integration:1  3)  orocrm_magento:sync_initial_integration:1  4) oro_integration:sync_integration:1  5) orocrm_magento:sync_initial_integration:1 all the Jobs Failed. My status error : https://justpaste.it/4rkcs  and log error : https://justpaste.it/61uta How can i solve the issue?